# What is prefered widget for each frame repaint job at flutter sdk?

Tags: user-interface, mobile, flutter

Im looking forward to test flutter memory/cpu usage. But I'm totaly lost at what widget do I pick for:

1. widget will contain custom canvas drawing(full screen)
2. widget must update itself 30 times per second(calling repaint from 0 each time)

in general, we have our own engine that revolves around uiview/surfaceview. I want to write same stuff on dart, connect to server, get same data, get same picture. But I dont unrestand what widget to take. As far as I see, I'l pick statefull widget and will change it state 30 timer per sec with timer. But that's not sounds right to me thought

Comment: Litteraly any widget will do.

Comment: I guess he wants a Canvas or CustomPaint. For the 30x/sec he could return the same result every 2nd time in `build()` and updated result the other times or just check how much time passed since the last time updated content was returned, but if this is not an exact multiply of the actual frame rate this could look ugly.

Comment: Sure, but all widgets manipulate the canvas too. A Container with a color that change every frame would do the same thing. We lack informations as is.

Comment: okay, I tried my own custom widget with custom painting. 5000 thousand lines on solid 60 fps. what magic is this.
So the way Il do it is to check how much time it takes to calculate frame+ draw it => sleep time required to get 30 fps on current second. 
The only issue I saw is that widget itself gets recreated each time I do state update, as far as I get- it is ok, because I litterally give current state with its scope to new widget instance, but is there a way to avoid memory alloc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ticker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/Ticker-class.html), which is the same mechanism that animations (i.e. [AnimationController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html)) use to update every frame.

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() => runApp(const CanvasWidget());

class CanvasWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CanvasWidget({super.key});
  @override
  State<CanvasWidget> createState() => _CanvasWidgetState();
}

class _CanvasWidgetState extends State<CanvasWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final drawState = DrawState();
  Ticker? ticker;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ticker = createTicker(tick);
    ticker!.start();
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    ticker?.stop();
    ticker?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: MyPainter(drawState),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  void tick(Duration elapsed) {
    var t = elapsed.inMicroseconds * 1e-6;
    double radius = 100;
    drawState.x = radius * math.sin(t);
    drawState.y = radius * math.cos(t);
    setState(() {});
  }
}

class DrawState {
  double x = 0, y = 0;
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final DrawState state;
  
  MyPainter(this.state);
  
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()..color = Colors.red;
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(state.x + size.width * 0.5, state.y + size.height * 0.5), 20, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```